# Adding Placeholder Kind of Functionality into React-Native Picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have set up a reusable drop-menu component in my React-native app that uses the native `picker`. The less than ideal situation I'm running into is that since there is no `placeholder` property available on `picker`, if I add 'Select Type' to the list of menu items, that will show up as an option in the menu that opens up. That's obviously not ideal. How can I work a placeholder kind of functionality into this, so that 'Select Type' is initially displayed without showing up in the menu that pops up when the user presses to open the menu?

```
{
  !this.state.otherTypeSelected ? 
  (
    <View style={styles.forms.fieldContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.forms.fieldLabel}>Type</Text>
      <DropDownMenu 
        style={styles.forms.pickerContainer}
        itemStyle={styles.forms.pickerItem}
        items={[
          { label: 'A', value: 'A' },
          { label: 'B', value: 'B' },
          { label: 'C', value: 'C' },
          { label: 'D', value: 'D'  },
          { label: 'Other', value: 'Other' }
        ]}
        onSelectMenuValue={this.handleContactTypeSelection}
       />
     </View>
   ) : null
}
```

And the `DropDownMenu` code looks like this:

```
export const DropDownMenu = (props) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={componentStyles.container}>
      <Picker
        {...props}
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
          props.onSelectMenuValue(itemValue), 
          setSelectedValue(itemValue)
        }}
      >
        {props.items.map(item => <Picker.Item label={item.label} value={item.value} />)}
      </Picker>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Note, while I could make my first menu item an empty string, with something like `{ label: '', value: 0 },` the space representing that value will still show up in my drop-menu, which is also not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you can add something like `<Picker.Item value='' label='Placeholder text...' />` inside the Picker. will that work for u?

Comment: I did think of that. But, if I'm understanding you correctly, the problem with that is that the space will still be there representing that empty string value in the drop menu - which is still not ideal, and feels a little hacky to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Picker` in react-native has been deprecated. There are only two methods in order to use the `Picker`

1. Use any library for Picker.
2. Create your own Picker (where you will have all the controls with you.)

You can create a simple `functional component` such as:

**Note:** This was created in 5 mins, so don't expect this to be pretty :P But it is working

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

// Dropdown Item component
const DropDownItem = (props) => {
  return <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    props.onPress(props.label)
    props.hideDropdown(false)
    }}>
    <Text>{props.label}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
}

// Custom Picker Component
const CustomPicker = () => {
  const [showValue, toggleView] = useState(false)
  const [selectedVal, changeValue] = useState('')

  return <>
  {selectedVal && <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeValue('')}>
      <Text>Clear Value</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>}
  <View style={styles.pickerView}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.placeholderView} onPress={() => toggleView(!showValue)}>
      <Text style>{selectedVal || "Select a value..."}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    {showValue && <View style={styles.dropDownView}>
    <DropDownItem label="Value 1" hideDropdown={toggleView} onPress={val => changeValue(val)} />
    <DropDownItem label="Value 2" hideDropdown={toggleView} onPress={val => changeValue(val)} />
    <DropDownItem label="Value 3" hideDropdown={toggleView} onPress={val => changeValue(val)} />
    </View>}
  </View>
  </>
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomPicker />    
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 40,
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  pickerView: {
    width: 160,
    height: 30,
    padding: 3,
  },
  placeholderView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
    padding: 3
  },
  dropDownView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 32
  }
});

export default App;
```

[image]

Link: https://snack.expo.io/MBb60jEQw

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Thanks. One note: getting an error when I run your code snippet: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: are you running it on the app or on any web tool? I also added the `expo link` for the above code. Please do check on that